# "Undefined variable $exams (View: /Users/pathparakh/Projects/relationship/resources/views/marks/create.blade.php)" in Laravel Relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

This Is My "Mark" Model.   I have 3 model linked with this model.

```
use HasFactory;

protected $table = 'marks';

protected $fillable = [
    'subject_id',
    'student_id',
    'exam_id',
    'mark',
];

public function exams() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Exam::class);
}

public function students() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Student::class);
}

public function subjects() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Subject::class);
}
```

This Is My Exam Model. this is linked with Mark model

```
use HasFactory;

protected $table = "exams";

protected $fillable = [
    'exam',
];

public function marks() {
    return $this->hasMany(Mark::class);
}
```

This Is My MarkController. This is my controller in which 3 model are linked

```
public function index()
{
    $marks = Mark::all();
    $students = Student::all();
    $subjects = Subject::all();
    $exams = Exam::all();
    return view('marks.index', compact('marks', 'students', 'subjects', 'exams'));
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    return view('marks.create');
}
```

This is my marks.create where error is occurring in line 20

```
<td>
    <select name="exam_id" id="exam_id" class="form-control">
        <option value="">Select One</option>
        @foreach ($exams as $exam)
        <option value="{{ $exam->id }}">{{ $exam->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</td>
```

Comment: Make `$exams` available in your `create()`  method and pass it to its view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this

```
public function index()
{
    $marks = Mark::all();
    $students = Student::all();
    $subjects = Subject::all();
    $exams = Exam::all();
    return view('marks.index', compact('marks', 'students', 'subjects', 'exams'));
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    $exams = Exam::all(); //this part is missing
    return view('marks.create', compact('exams'));
}
```